# top 2 images figcatpion hide when i position header fixed

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make website but problem is that when i position header fix top 2 images figcatipion hide. I am trying to make website but problem is that when i position header fix top 2 images figcatipion hide.

```css
/*********************
General
*********************/
* {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
 font-family: sans-serif;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}

h1, h3 {
 margin: 0;
}

/*********************
Header
*********************/
.main-header {
 background-color: #3cb371;
 width: 100%;
 float: left;
 text-align: center;
 position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
}

.logo {
 font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
.name {
 padding-top: 5px;
}
.occptn {
 padding-bottom: 15px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.main-header a {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 0;
}

.main-nav {
 background-color:#2e8b57;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.main-nav a {
 text-align: center;
}

.main-nav li {
 display: inline-block;
  padding: 15px;
 
}

.selected a:visited {
 color: #000;
}

.main-nav a:hover {
 color: #000;
}

/*********************
Images
*********************/

.container figure {
 margin: 0;
 float: left;
  width: 45%;
 padding: 0 20px ;
 
}

.container img {
 max-width: 100%;
 display: block;
 
}

.container figcaption {
 clear: right;
 background-color: #dcdcdc;
 padding: 10px 0;
 font-size: .8em;
 }
 
 .figureOne , 
 .figureTwo {
  
 }

.clearfix::after {
  content: “”;
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

/*********************
Footer
*********************/
.main-footer {
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
 background-color:   #7fffd4;
 clear: left;
 padding: 20px;
}
.main-footer a {
 
}
/*********************
Responsive Layout
*********************/

@media (min-width:660px) {
 
 .main-header {
  padding: 10px 0;
  box-shadow: 0 5px #2e8b57;
 }
 
 .logo {
  float: left;
  width: 45%;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 20px;
  
 }
 

 .main-nav {
  background-color: #3cb371;
  float: right;
  width: 45%;
 }
 
 .main-nav li {
  
  padding-left: 10px ;
 }
 
 .occptn {
  padding: 0;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Irfan Hussain | Web Developer</title>
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Indie+Flower" rel="stylesheet"> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="normalize.css" />
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>
<body>
  <!-- Start Header -->
 <header class="main-header">
   <a class="logo" href="index.html">
  <h1 class="name"> Irfan Hussain </h1> 
  <h3 class="occptn">  Web Developer </h3>
  </a>
  <ul class="main-nav">
   <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
 </header> 
 <!-- End Header -->
 <div class="container clearfix">
 <figure class="figureOne"> 
 <figcaption> Experimentation with color and texture. </figcaption> 
 <img src="img/numbers-01.jpg" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
 </figure>
 
 <figure class="figureTwo">
 <figcaption> Playing with blending mode in photoshop. </figcaption>
 <img src="img/numbers-02.jpg" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
 </figure>
 
 <figure>
 <figcaption> Trying to create 80's style glow. </figcaption>
 <img src="img/numbers-06.jpg" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
 </figure>
 
 <figure>
 <figcaption> Drips created using Photoshop brushes </figcaption> 
 <img src="img/numbers-09.jpg" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
 </figure>
 
  <figure> 
 <figcaption> Creating shapes using repetition. </figcaption>
 <img src="img/numbers-12.jpg" alt="Irfan Web Developer" />
  </figure>
 </div>
 
 <footer class="main-footer"> 
 <p> &copy2018 Copy right Irfan Hussain | Web Developer </p>
 <a href="https://www.facebook.com"> <img src="img/facebook-wrap.png" alt="Facebook" /> </a>
 <a href="https://www.twitter.com"> <img src="img/twitter-wrap.png" alt="Twitter" /> </a>
 </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I am trying to make website but problem is that when i position header fix top 2 images figcatipion hide.

Comment: give your container some padding top

Comment: when screen resolution less than 760 caption hide.

Comment: Pete its work thanks. r u Web Developer?